# Reaching vertex d in a tetrahedron in n steps

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was solving this problem:

Given a tetrahedron with vertices A, B, C and D. An ant is standing at vertex D. The ant won't sit idle. It will keep on moving from one vertex to another along some edge of the tetrahedron. Your task is to count the number of ways in which the ant can go from the initial vertex D to itself in exactly n steps.

So for input 2
Output :
3

I was able to solve this comfortably using recursion the following way. But it seems not very efficient for a large input, say, 15 because of its time complexity.

This can be solved through dynamic programming but I don't see any scope of memoization in my current approach. Maybe I need to change the approach. So appreciate any help.

I would like to solve it using recursion + memoization

```js
var count = 0;
function recursion(n, arr=['d']){
    if(n <=1) return 0;
  
  if(arr.length === n+1 && arr[arr.length-1] ==='d'){
    console.log(arr.join(" -> "))
    count++;
    return;
  }

  if(arr.length > n+1) return;

  for(let el of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']){
    if(arr[arr.length-1] != el){
       recursion(n, [...arr, el]);
    }
  }
}
recursion(3)

console.log(count);
```

Comment: If you consider the adjacency matrix M, ie the matrix M indexed by the vertices of the graph such that `M[i, j]` is 1 iff (i, j) is an edge and 0 if it is not an edge, then for any integer k >= 0, `M^k [i, j]` is the number of distinct ways to move from i to j in exactly k steps (where `M^k` is the kth power of matrix M; this can be computed as `math.pow(M, k)`). For your tetrahedron, `M = [[0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use memoization here.

First let's analyse the recurrence relationships.

Define:

- to be the number of paths of length  to go from a vertex to itself.
- to be the number of paths of length  to go from one vertex to a chosen *different* one. It doesn't matter which destination vertex we choose, since the tetrahedron is completely symmetric.

Now the recurrence relationships:

To get the number of paths of length  to the original vertex (), you can choose a neighbor from three neighbors and then count the number of (shorter) paths from there back to the start vertex, which is given by . So:

= 3<sub>−1</sub>

To get the number of paths of length  to a *different* vertex (), you can either choose *that* neighbor and count the number of (1 step shorter) paths from there to itself, or you can choose one of the other two neighbors and count the number of (1 step shorter) paths from there to the target vertex. So:

= <sub>−1</sub> + 2<sub>−1</sub>

The latter equation can be expanded by substitution to this recurrence relationship:

= 3<sub>−2</sub> + 2<sub>−1</sub>

As we reference −2, we need to have at least two base cases:

- <sub>0</sub> = 0 (there are no paths of size 0 that bring you to another vertex)
- <sub>1</sub> = 1 (there is one path of size 1 from one vertex to another)

#### Implementation

As we have a nice recurrence relationship for , we could first implement a function that returns the number of paths from one vertex to *another one*. And then use the first relation to translate the original query (for the number of paths to the *same* vertex) into that problem:

```js
// Memoize the number of paths from one vertex to a different one
const memo = new Map().set(0, 0).set(1, 1);

function numPathsToOther(size) {
    let result = memo.get(size);
    if (result === undefined) {
        result = 3*numPathsToOther(size-2) + 2*numPathsToOther(size-1);
        memo.set(size, result);
    }
    return result;
}

function numPathsToSelf(size) {
    return size ? 3 * numPathsToOther(size - 1) : 1;
}

// Demo runs for the first few path-sizes:
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i, numPathsToSelf(i));
     console.log((3*0^i-(-4)^i)/4)
}
```

#### Example

Let's say we label the four vertices as , , , and  as you did, and that  is 3. We want to know the number of paths of size  that start and end in vertex .

There are three ways to start that path: →, → or →. Let's take →. Now we need to know how many paths there are of size 2 that start in  and end in .

Here, let's stop for a minute. You can get to the realisation that there is nothing special about  and . They are just neighbors, but here it comes: *any two* vertices in a tetrahedron are neighbors, and relate to each other in the same way as  to . So we can generalise this case as *"the number of paths from one vertex to another"*!

For the case where the size of such path needs to be 2, there are only two possible paths from  that end in : either we go via , or we go via .

Now we go back to the initial situation. We said that paths of size 3 from  back to  could pass first via , and now we know that from  there are two possibilities. But we could also have gone from  to , or from  to . And as the tetrahedron is completely symmetric we can immediately conclude that also those two alternatives each represent 2 paths. So in total we have found 3x2=6 paths.

This little analysis shows that it is useful to know what the number of paths are from some vertex to *another* vertex.

### Closed formula

The recurrence relationship has a solution. [oeis.org](https://oeis.org/A054878) provides it:

> Number of closed walks of length n along the edges of a tetrahedron based at a vertex.
>
> FORMULA a(n) = (3^n + (-1)^n*3)/4.

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i, (3**i + (-1)**i*3)/4)
}
```

Comment: The more I read, the more I appreciate deep insights you have. Few queries:
*To get the number of paths of length  to a different vertex (), you can either choose that neighbor and count the number of (shorter) paths from there to itself,*

1. Wouldn't the shortest path from a different vertex to itself will always be 1? Also, if possible can you please explain the whole thought process with an example, say, n=3 and starting vertex, D'?

2. How did you arrive at the intuition that *Dn* (number of path having length n to **different vertex**) needs to be there in the equation?

Comment: With shorter I did not mean *shortest*, but exactly *one step* shorter. I have updated my answer to add that precision, and an analysis of the case of =3. It includes the realisation why it is useful to define the notion of the number of paths between *different* nodes ().

Comment: Got it. What was confusing to me initially was why we were calculating Dn instead of just D(n-1) since we’re at the other vertex after taking one step. I guess that’s just a expression in Oder to derive the recurrence relation in general for n and that would give us the result of n-1 as well. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.